# executing USE-statement yields "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a weird escaping problem. USE-statement does not work as I would expect. Here are three statements I tried, but only the last one works:

```
engine=create_engine("mysql+pymysql://l:pw@myserver")
engine.execute("use :db", db='mydb')  # fails
engine.execute("use 'mydb'")          # fails
engine.execute("use `mydb`")          # works fine
```

Failing stements raise exception "You have an error in your SQL syntax...". I checked with strace the queries that are sent over the wire, it's "use 'mydb'". But this query executed from MySQL cli works just fine. Why it doesn't work from within SQLAlchemy?

PS I tried using "SET sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES" and updated SQLAlchemy and PyMySQL to the latest versions. Also tried mysqlclient driver, no luck.

Comment: You cannot pass identifiers (table names, column names, etc.) using placeholders.

Comment: It looks so. Is there is a better way to change the database? I didn't find any but "USE %s" % db, but this is unsafe. The only option I see is to manually call sqlalchemy's function to escape data.

Comment: It's not unsafe if you whitelist the list of database names.